# Protobuf-Net seems to reuse existing object instead of creating and assigning a new one

Tags: c#, deserialization, protobuf-net

In the following code, there are 2 static Statuses: Initial Status and Last Status. When Test class first gets created, it gets created with a status of InitialStatus. This status can get changed by a separate call (ChangeStatus).

When I create an object of TestClass and change its status and then proto serialize and deserialize that object, it looks like it overwrites the value in InitialStatus. So in essence Protobuf seems to reuse an existing object if one is available when it deserializes data. (But if the object is null, it doesnt do that). Is there some way I can customize this behavior so that after deserialization, the object will be reconstructed instead of reusing the existing variable?

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Status
{
    private static Status _initialStatus;
    public static Status InitialStatus
    {
        get{
            if (_initialStatus == null)
            {
                _initialStatus = new Status{StatusId=-1};
            }
            return _initialStatus;
        }
    }

    private static Status _lastStatus;
    public static Status LastStatus
    {
        get{
            if (_lastStatus == null)
            {
                _lastStatus = new Status{StatusId=-2};
            }
            return _lastStatus;
        }
    }

    [ProtoMember(101)]
    public int StatusId{get; private set;}
}

[ProtoContract]
public class TestClass2
{
    public TestClass2()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        CurrentStatus = Status.InitialStatus;
    }

    [ProtoMember(101)]
    public Status CurrentStatus{get; private set;}

    public void ChangeStatus(Status newStatus)
    {
        CurrentStatus = newStatus;
    }
}


void Main()
{
    TestClass2 test = new TestClass2();

    test.ChangeStatus(Status.LastStatus);


    string serializedTest = ProtoUtils.Serialize(test);
    TestClass2 testDeserialized = ProtoUtils.Deserialize<TestClass2>(serializedTest);

    Debug.Assert(Status.InitialStatus.StatusId == -1, "Initial Status has changed");
    Debug.Assert(Status.LastStatus.StatusId == -2, "Last Status has changed");
}


public static class ProtoUtils
{
    public static string Serialize(Object o)
    {
        String result = String.Empty;

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(stream, o);

            result = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
        }
        result.Dump();
        return result;
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string data)
    {
        T result = default(T);

        if (data != null)
        {
            byte[] dataBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data);

            using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(dataBytes))
            {
                result = Serializer.Deserialize<T>(stream);
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide the code for `ProtoUtils` so I can test this on my end?

Answer (score 1):

Options:

- specify SkipConstructor on the ProtoContractAttribute - this will prevent the field being initialized during object creation
- use a before-deserialization callback (an instance method decorated with the appropriate attribute) and wipe the field - this happens after construction but before it reads data

Comment: I should have specified this in my question, but I cant skip constructor. Mainly because in my actual code the constructor does do additional work that I cant skip. And I was hoping to not use callbacks.

Comment: @RajRao personally I'd still use the combination of skipped constructor and callback (to run exactly the required code) - but how about a custom factory instead? A third option I didn't mention is that you can get protobuf-net to use a static method to create instances, which could then be initialized any way you like